# trying to delete null rows with an Id

Tags: android, rows

I am working in android with five rows in my table; _id, title, type, platform, body.  I have some rows that have null Columns, the _id is an auto increment field so it will never be null.

The problem I am having is that I cannot delete the rows that have been created that have null values, except for the _id.

Here is what have tried:
public boolean deleteBlankRecord(long rowId) {

```
   return mDb.delete(DATABASE.TABLE,KEY_TITLE + "=" + title, null)  > 0;
```

Can any one suggest something else?

Comment: Can you post the generated query for that delete() call?

Answer (score 2):

I think your miss understanding how the delete function works. try using the _id to delete the rows.

```
return mDb.delete(DATABASE.TABLE,KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null)  > 0;
```